# mysqld_multi on the same data directory? 1 RW / 1 RO

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to have 2 mysql instances who use the same data directory?
One instance in read-write mode and the other in read only (global variable) on the same machine?
Is there some parameters will i have to be cautious with? like the logs?
Is that the global variable "read_only" will work in the [mysqldxxx] section? as far i can read in the doc, it works.

if someone has already experienced this config i will be glad to hear about it and the problems he has faced

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended (in the strongest way) to have two MySQL instances use the same data files.  If you're setting up multiple instances on the same machine, you need separate:

1. Socket
2. Network port
3. Configuration
4. Data files & caches
5. Logs

To achieve the same effect, you could set up replication between two servers on the same machine, so that you could read from the slave and make changes on the master which get replicated to the slave.

See this doc for more information on running multiple MySQL instances on one machine: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-servers.html

Comment: From [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqld-multi.html]: Beware of the dangers of using multiple mysqld servers with the same data directory. Use separate data directories, unless you know what you are doing. It seems possible right?

Comment: It's "possible" but really really really really not a good idea.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-data-directories.html says explicitly that you shouldn't have two instances writing to the same datafiles.  I know you're saying you'd use readonly which should stop one instance from writing - but it's really strongly not recommended.

Comment: Also note the limitation that this only works for MyISAM/Merge storage engines.

Comment: i hadn't seen that. But they talk about concurrent write and that's not what i want. The reason why i want this kind of configuration is because i have no space left to duplicate the database and i need to emulate a replication with a read_only server for the developpment team.

Comment: MySQL 5.6 added the ability for running [read-only with InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-read-only-instance.html).  Also, take a look at [MyEnv](http://www.fromdual.com/myenv-mysql-basenv) as a replacement for mysqld_multi.

Comment: Thanks @yoonix! It seems that's what i was looking for. I will give it a try